# Laravel 8 unit test - can I mock a model so I can fake the data value instead of check what the values in the db?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking

I have this service class and I want to test this method but how can I mock a model and set the value of shouldReturn for those model method calls all() and where() in my test? The below didn't set the rates at all and still use the rates in db. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    $currencyMock = Mockery::mock(Currency::class);

    // // Set up the expectation for Currency::all() and keyBy('iso_code')
    $currencyData = [
        'USD' => new Currency(['iso_code' => 'USD', 'current_rate' => 1.0, 'previous_rate' => 1.0]),
        'EUR' => new Currency(['iso_code' => 'EUR', 'current_rate' => 0.8, 'previous_rate' => 0.9]),
        'GBP' => new Currency(['iso_code' => 'GBP', 'current_rate' => 1.2, 'previous_rate' => 1.1]),
        'CAD' => new Currency(['iso_code' => 'CAD', 'current_rate' => 1.3, 'previous_rate' => 1.2]),
    ];
    $currencyMock->shouldReceive('all')->andReturn(Collection::make($currencyData));
    $this->app->instance(Currency::class, $currencyMock);
    $currencyService = new CurrencyConversionService();
    $results = $currencyService->currencyRates([
        'base_currency' => 'USD',
        'iso_codes' => ['EUR', 'GBP']
    ]);
    dd($results);

public function currencyRates(array $params): Collection
{
    $new_currencies = new Collection();
    if (!isset($params['base_currency'])) {
        return $new_currencies;
    }
    if (!isset($params['iso_codes'])) {
        $currencies = Currency::all()->keyBy('iso_code');
    } else {
        $tmp_currencies = array_merge($params['iso_codes'], [$params['base_currency']]);
        $currencies = Currency::whereIn('iso_code', $tmp_currencies)->get()->keyBy('iso_code');
    }
    if (strtolower($params['base_currency']) == config('currency.base_currency')) {
        $new_currencies = $currencies;
    } else {
        foreach ($currencies as $key => $currency) {
            if ($key == $params['base_currency']) continue;
            $currency->current_rate = round(($currency->current_rate / $currencies[$params['base_currency']]->current_rate) * 1, 5);
            $currency->previous_rate = round(($currency->previous_rate / $currencies[$params['base_currency']]->previous_rate) * 1, 5);
            $currency->base_currency = $params['base_currency'];
            $new_currencies[] = $currency;
        }
    }
    return $new_currencies;
}
```

Comment: Mock active record - bad practice. You can add Repository layer (too bad) and mock repositories OR use testing database (sqlite or mysql with tmpfs)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think you are learning about testing, that is why you are asking about this, but I saw this type of question so many times, that I am tired already. So, do not mock any model, because you are then testing the framework, not exactly your code, and it can get very difficult, you must take into account so many things, like global scopes, or local scopes and more, and you do not want to mock that. Just use a factory and use a fake database to run tests on and that's it, if you need more help, check my profile, I have some Q&A in there about testing that could help you

Comment: No problem. Yes I'm learning testing. I have local mysql db for tests so it's ok. It's just the reason I'm thinking to mock the model is that then I don't have to know what's the value in db or worry someone else added tests to change db that will no longer match my values in the tests if I don't mock it.

Comment: I was thinking to use database transaction to update the db values that I want to test then when I'm done then rollback but then it will add some extra time in terms of speed on overall tests if I do this alot. So I thought using mock then it kind of skipping the db updates, etc.

Comment: @sparkmix so, if you mock a model, and fake the value, you want to test something that is not the model, that makes total sense, I recommend that you share the code test next time so we know better what you are trying to achieve. But if someone changes the database (with a migration) and then your test fails due to it, that is totally fine and desired, it changed how it was supposed to be, so new places are possibly broken and must be fixed due to the change, that is why you have tests. Use traits to help you with the database (see next comment)

Comment: Use the trait [`RefreshDatabase`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test), it will help you a lot, and remember to have your local database (for example, named `app`) but also have another database (schema) for the tests, so they do not interfere with the existing data (for example, named `app_test`, and update `phpunit.xml` -> `DB_DATABASE=app_test` so it uses that new schema)